# My gained reputation for today is not showing up on the Achievements dropdown

Tags: bug, top-bar, achievements-dialog

I've made 30 points on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21629418/) today.

But this reputation is not showing up in the Achievements dropdown: accessible by clicking the icon to the right of the Inbox button.

My reputation counter is OK though.

Following the +2 on this question, I can see the +10 reputation for meta, but not the points for SO.

[image: Achievements dropdown]

Comment: When you click on the icon, what does the dropdown show? What browser and what OS are you using?

Comment: Have you placed a bounty **anywhere on the network** recently?

Comment: I haven't placed a bounty. I'm using Chrome. The dropdown shows the achievements as at the end of yesterday.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, I wasn't notified about the acheivements but when I clicked the box the messages were there.

Comment: I see you deleted the answer then undeleted it. Maybe the achievements dialog check if post was ever deleted instead of checking current status. @Oded can you follow this lead?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that might be the case.

Comment: @Oded cheers, want me try and reproduce?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - asking around first

Comment: @Oded bump... did you have a chance to ask around?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - did ask, and though we did see the issue, were not able to repro.

Comment: @Oded OK, will try to repro by deleting then undeleting my next answer then I'll keep watch and see if I get upvotes and it won't appear in the top bar it's a bingo.

Comment: @Sha Ever had a chance to test this?

Comment: @AmalMurali wasn't able to reproduce after all. :(